# Нужен совет по написанию игры с постоянным подключением к GPS

Tags: android, google-maps-api, gps

Здравствуйте, я собираюсь написать некое подобие игры Pokemon GO. Вместо покемонов обычные точки (на выбор 30), выбрал одну, остальные исчезают, показываются другие игроки, идущие к ней. Успел, пришел, подтвердил местоположение, получил опыт. Не успел, пришел кто-то другой, не получил опыт. Это получается, что подключение к GPS спутникам будет **беспрерывное**! Беспрерывно должны отправляться координаты игрока, чтобы у других не писались ложные данные. Беспрерывно должен обновляться статус точки (пришли, не пришли). А ведь на улице зарядного устройства нет, а power бланки не у всех имеются, да и телефон будет нагреваться.

Что можно сделать? У меня несколько вопросов в плане реализации

1) Нужно что-то супер точное, чтобы местоположение было максимально правильным

2) Нужно сделать сервис игры безобидным, очень волнуюсь за батареи игроков

3) Если игрок получит травмы, засмотревшись на экран или побежав к точке на дорогу или в чужой дом? Нужно будет лицензионное соглашение?

4) Не забанят ли в GP? Не видел там покемон го, и вообще других аналогов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Супер точное местоположение это миф (в Google Maps), даже в Pokemon Go порой разброс большой.
2. Опять же на примере Pokemon Go, батарея улетает очень быстро, а из функций, относящихся к сохранению батареи, только лишь заставка с затемненным экраном, когда опускаешь телефон - то бишь сенсор.
3. В Pokemon Go порой выскакивают диалоги с надписями типа: "Не играйте за рулем", "Смотрите по сторонам". Лиц. соглашение обязательно нужно будет писать т.к. собираетесь хранить местоположение игроков на своем сервере.
4. Не должны

P.S. А вообще трудности будут не сколько с батареей, а с борьбой фейк местоположения. Данный труд выстрелит до первых отзывах о читерах.

Comment: Модуль xposed нужно будет изучить (по поводу  fakeGPS) спасибо за информацию